# Performing INSERT for each row in a select RESULT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

First, a general description of the problem: I'm running a periodical process which updates total figures in a table.  The issue is, that multiple updates may be required in each execution of the process, and each execution depends on the previous results.

My question is, can it be done in a single SQL Server SP?

My code (I altered it a little to simply the sample):

```
INSERT INTO CustomerMinuteSessions(time, customer, sessions, bytes, previousTotalSessions)
SELECT MS.time,
           MS.customer,
           MS.totalSessions,
           MS.totalBytes,
           CTS.previousTotalSessions
FROM (SELECT time, customer, SUM(sessions) as totalSessions, SUM(bytes) AS totalBytes
      FROM MinuteSessions
      WHERE time > @time
      GROUP BY time, x) MS
CROSS APPLY TVF_GetPreviousCustomerTotalSessions(MS.customer) CTS
ORDER BY time
```

The `previousTotalSessions` column depends on other rows in `UpdatedTable`, and its value is retrieved by `CROSS APPLY`ing `TVF_GetPreviousCustomerTotalSessions`, but if I execute the SP as-is, all the rows use the value retrieved by the function without taking the rows added *during* the execution of the SP.

For the sake of completeness, here's `TVF_GetPreviousCustomerTotalSessions`:

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[TVF_GetCustomerCurrentSessions] 
(   
    @customerId int
)
RETURNS @result TABLE (PreviousNumberOfSessions int)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @result
    SELECT TOP 1 (PreviousNumberOfSessions + Opened - Closed) AS PreviousNumberOfSessions
    FROM CustomerMinuteSessions 
    WHERE CustomerId = @customerId 
    ORDER BY time DESC

    IF @@rowcount = 0
        INSERT INTO @result(PreviousNumberOfSessions) VALUES(0)

    RETURN
END
```

What is the best (i.e. without for loop, I guess...) to take previous rows within the query for subsequent rows?

Comment: SQL edition? Are you trying to store an increment session count on each record or the total with each entry?

Comment: @Volvox: What happened to your answer (and to my comments and edits following it)??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL-2005 and later, you can do it with few CTEs in one shot.  If you use SQL-2000 you'll can use inline table-valued function.

Personally I like the CTE approach more, so I'm including a schematic translation of your code to CTEs syntax. (Bare in mind hat I didn't prepare a test set to check it).

```
WITH LastSessionByCustomer AS  
(
    SELECT CustomerID, MAX(Time)
    FROM CustomerMinuteSessions
    GROUP BY CustomerID
)
, GetPreviousCustomerTotalSessions AS
(
    SELECT LastSession.CustomerID, LastSession.PreviousNumberOfSessions + LastSession.Opened - LastSession.Closed AS PreviousNumberOfSessions
    FROM CustomerMinuteSessions LastSession
    INNER JOIN LastSessionByCustomer ON LastSessionByCustomer.CustomerID = LastSession.CustomerID
)
, MS AS
(
    SELECT time, customer, SUM(sessions) as totalSessions, SUM(bytes) AS totalBytes
    FROM MinuteSessions
    WHERE time > @time
    GROUP BY time, x
)
INSERT INTO CustomerMinuteSessions(time, customer, sessions, bytes, previousTotalSessions)
SELECT MS.time,
           MS.customer,
           MS.totalSessions,
           MS.totalBytes,
           ISNULL(GetPreviousCustomerTotalSessions.previousTotalSessions, 0)
FROM MS 
RIGHT JOIN GetPreviousCustomerTotalSessions ON MS.Customer = GetPreviousCustomerTotalSessions.CustomerID
```

Going a bit beyond your question, I think that your query with cross apply could make big damage to the database once table CustomerMinuteSessions database grows
I would add an index like to improve your chances of getting Index-Seek:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_CustomerMinuteSessions_CustomerId
    ON CustomerMinuteSessions (CustomerId, [time] DESC, PreviousNumberOfSessions, Opened, Closed );
```

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012.  I've found an excellent article [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals), which storngly directs me towards SQL 2012 Windows or cursors.  The problem with the Windows is that I can't figure out a solution for my function, which is not similar to SQL Server's ''Sum''.

Comment: Indeed, it's and excellent article! maybe I misunderstood you, but I think this is not your case, I didn't see that you are accumulating in a way the article defines, you are just reading the latest rows based on a variable `time > @time` and then joining them with customers in the function `WHERE CustomerId = @customerId`. So it still believe that my approach is valid.